# texlive does not find sty file

Tags: packages, installing, texlive, ubuntu, linux

I am on Ubuntu 8.04 and just install TeX Live with :

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-full.
```

I tried to compile my `.tex` file with TexMaker. 
I get :

1. `xcolor.sty not found`
2. `titlesec.sty not found`

How can I fix the problem ?

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you have all neccesary packages installed:

- `xcolor` is provided by the package [`texlive-latex-recommended`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/texlive-latex-recommended/filelist)
- `titlesec` is provided by the package [`texlive-latex-extra`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/texlive-latex-extra/filelist)

You can install them with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-recommended texlive-latex-extra
```

You can also try to use [`tlmgr`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/tlmgr.1.html) to install missing packages for the current user (tlmgr in Debian/ubuntu runs always in user mode).

The texlive distribution provided by ubuntu is usually pretty old. You might want to consider to install a newer version manually.

Comment: sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra indeed solves the problem. I don't see any issues now in 2015.

Comment: texlive-latex-extra is only 500MB vs the 2GB of the parent texlive-full package.  This answer is preferable IMHO.

Comment: `texlive-latex-extra` just helped me with a missing `pgfcore.sty`.

Comment: I think on Ubuntu 18.04, `latex-xcolor` doesn't exist anymore. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JasonLiu Seems like xcolor is now in `texlive-latex-recommended`. I'll edit this answer

Answer (score 8):

I am not entirely sure what version of texlive is on Ubuntu 8.04. Haven't the repos deprecated? I.e. your packages are very old.

I suggest you do a manual installation. See [texlive 2011](http://www.tug.org/texlive/). It is actually not that difficult.
If you do this please remember to uninstall `texlive-full`, and others, using your package manager.

Comment: ubuntu packges don't have tlmgr

Comment: @someonr thanks, I will remove that statement.

Comment: In more recent ubuntu version `tlmgr` is included, but runs in user mode (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/tlmgr.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here I am in 2020 and I found that TeXWorks (Version 0.6.2 (Debian) [r.7ecce17, 2017-04-29 10:23 AM]) could not find the `xcolor` package from my TeXLive 2019 installation on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS while another IDE like TeXMaker could do it.

The fix was to bump up the path where the `.sty` file gets copied to (or the soft link to it anyway): `/usr/local/bin`, in the tab for Typesetting in the Preferences dialogue that is reached through the Edit/Preferences menu from the menu toolbar in the main window.